# Ember find average of key elements

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to this computed property to work by selecting individual scores of a movie, and finding the average.  It's been a bit tricky, but this is what I have so far...

```
testing: Ember.computed('movie.title', 'movie.rating', function() {
  return this.get('movie.title') + ', ' + this.get('movie.rating');
}),

averageScore: Ember.computed('review.@each.score', function() { //Used to determine each score of review
  return this.get('review').(function(sum, review) {
    return sum += review.get('score');
  }, 0) / this.get('reviews').get('length');
}),
```

I know I'm missing something, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`sum` is built-in:

```
scores:       Ember.computed.mapBy('review', 'score'),
sumOfScores:  Ember.computed.sum('scores'),
averageScore: Ember.computed('sumOfScores', 'scores.length', function() {
  return this.get('sumOfScores') / this.get('scores.length');
}
```